# Access Report ignores DISTINCROW in query

Tags: ms-access

I have a report that gets the data from a query. The query itself has DISTINCTROW in the SQL. However, when I use the query as the record source for the report, it outputs data as if DINSTINCTROW was not decalred in the the query (Unique Records).

Is there some option that I forgot to add while selecting the query as the report's record source?
I've tried copying and pasting the SQL code into the reports record source, but there was no difference.

Query Result: DISTINCT (same as ALL)

```
A       B       C       D               
5669    7625    7625    $680.00
5677    7635    7635    $1,448.75
5757    7751    7751    $562.50
5776    7773    7773    $825.00
5796    7796    7796    $53.75
5810    7814    7814    $150.00
```

Query Result: DISTINCTROW

```
A       B       C       D           
5669    7625    7625    $156.25
5677    7635    7635    $30.00
5757    7751    7751    $180.00
5776    7773    7773    $15.00
5796    7796    7796    $31.25
5810    7814    7814    $120.00
```

Comment: what results do you get from the report?

Comment: If there is no JOIN in the SQL statement here, then DISTINCTROW will be of no use whatsoever. If there are no duplicates in the version without DISTINCT or DISTINCTROW, then there is no reason to use DISTINCT, either. You only use DISTINCT to remove duplicates. What sorting and grouping is defined in the report? That can have a major effect on what data gets displayed.

Comment: ...and let me add, if you'd give us the SQL of the report's Recordsource, it would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if in the report, the displayed fields are not in the Detail section but in a grouping section such as header section or footer section. If it's so, then the Report displays only grouped values, i.e. distinct values.

Comment: the displayed fields are in the Detail section

Comment: What is the Access version? Does the query use tables that are linked to a non-Access database? The property Source of the Report is the name of the query or the same SQL statement as the query?

Comment: Access 2007. The Query runs of some other queries, which are linked to an access database table.

edit: Source of the Report is the name of the query, but I have tried the sql statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be if the query's `'unique values'` property is set to `yes`, or if the query's sql begins `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Are you sure you're not doing additional joins in your report `recordsource`?  If you create a new blank report off your query, does it only return distinct rows?

---

In response to your comment, if a blank report based on the query returns non-distinct rows, then the problem is with the query.  Have you checked the recordcounts to see if they match?  Maybe it 'looks' like the query's returning distinct rows, but it really isn't.
If a blank report based on the query returned distinct rows, on the other hand, you could be sure your query was ok and there was something introducing additional rows within the report.

---

Also, `DISTINCT` and `DISTINCTROW` return different results- you want `DISTINCT`, not `DISTINCTROW`.  Check the `'unique values'` property of the query.

---

`'unique values'` and `'unique rows'` are two different things, you can check the help files.  You want `'unique values'`.

Comment: the sql query begins with SELECT `SELECT DISTINCTROW` and the report 'recordsource' is not joined. I have tried it on a blank query, and it still gets the data as if `DISTINCTROW` isn't in the query

Comment: The record count is the same regardless of `Unique Records`. However, the data in one column changes significantly (the numbers are much smaller). However, the other columns do not change.

Comment: the data does not change at all regardless of `unique values` being `on / off`. Only `Unique Rows` change the data

Comment: OK, let's start over.  I'm assuming your rowcounts are different between the query and the report, the report being higher, as if distinctRow was not applied.  Is that the case?  That you're seeing duplicate rows on the new report you don't see in the query?

Comment: I've edited main post with example query results. The Report always displays the results from `DISTINCT / ALL`, regardless of what I change.

Answer (score 0):

In the query, replace DISTINCTROW with DISTINCT.

Reference: [Prédicats ALL, DISTINCT, DISTINCTROW, TOP](http://office.microsoft.com/fr-fr/access-help/predicats-all-distinct-distinctrow-top-HA001231351.aspx)